# Indexing: placing the letter sigma in the letter s section

Tags: indexing, sorting

I'm working on the index of my thesis and have the word σ-algebra. I would like this to appear with words starting with s. How can I do this please? Right now it appears at the top. I tried using the babel in this way

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,latexsym,amsxtra}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{ax}{Axiom}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[thm]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{prob}[thm]{Problem}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}

\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}


\makeindex

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle


\tableofcontents


\mainmatter

\index{sand|see{grains}}
\index{\greektext s \latintext algebra|see{sigma algebra}}
\index{road|see{street}}
%    Include main chapters here.
\include{}



\backmatter

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is rather long. Please remove anything that isn't necesssary to explain your problem.

Comment: It's just the standard amsbook template - basically all I added to it is the babel package and some indexing.

Comment: It may be a standard template, etc. but all this code is distracting. You stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to your question if the latter is to-the-point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't use Greek for this, but math mode.

With

```
\index{x@y}
```

you index “y”, but sorting it as if it was “x”.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\title{x}\author{y}
\frontmatter

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle


\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\chapter{X}
\index{sand|see{grains}}
\index{sigma-algebra@$\sigma$-algebra|see{sigma algebra}}
\index{road|see{street}}
\index{street}
\index{grains}
\index{sigma algebra}

\backmatter

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]